# Facebook connect via django-socialregistration

Tags: django, redirect, facebook

I'm trying to add Facebook connect to my project. I've searched the web and came across to [django-socialregistration](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration).

I followed all required instructions and all of them works properly. I've created a test page and put all necessary template_tags and Facebook button is shown my page. The problem is when I'm trying to connect via Facebook, i'm redirected to an error page which says :

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

Possibly my app settings are wrong. Here is my app settings for my domain :

```
Site URL : http://localhost:8000/test
Site Domain : localhost
```

I thought, I'm getting this error because the django-socialregistration redirects my page to its previously defined url. I found that, it uses _get_next() function. But I couldn't figure out how to pass my own url to this function.

So, how can i resolve this error ? From my app settings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Facebook is not working properly with `localhost` domains. What I am usually doing is adding a host name `example.com` to my `/etc/hosts` file as an alias for `localhost`. When you then change you site URL to `http://example.com/test` and the domain to `example.com` it should work with Facebook.

Not sure this is really fixing your problem since I never had this particular error message.